# Add a css class to <p> tags if error condition is TRUE

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, addclass

Setting up an error condition so that when the condition is true a css class will be added.

For example, when the condition is FALSE `<p></p>` do nothing, if TRUE add a class. `<p class="error"></p>`.

Here is the jquery I am using to add the calls but it not working.

http://jsfiddle.net/hookedonweb/7XhGC/1/

Comment: Works fine if you enable jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/7XhGC/2/

Comment: I firebuged it in jsFiddle and see that it is working but when I add it into a wordpress page `<script type="text/javascript">$("p.wpm_err").filter(function(){return $(this).text().replace(/\s/g,"").length!=0}).addClass("wpm_err-wrapper");</script>` I get an undefined error.

Comment: Here is the error: http://www.screencast.com/t/h0fhAcHIysU

Comment: What is the exact error? Have you included jQuery in your WordPress page? Is that little `<script>` at the bottom or top of the page?

Comment: the error in in my comment above. I am adding it inside a wordpress plugin that permits custom html. I have added <script> into this area before. I am add the script before the <p> tag I am targeting or after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this example gets an array of all p tags and for each one with empty innerHTML sets the class (you may want to getAttribute and concatenate the new string to the old first if you don't want to replace existing classes) also older versions of IE may use className

```
var ptags=document.getElementsByTagName("p")
for(var i=0;i<ptags.length;i++)
    if(ptags[i].innerHTML=="")
        ptags[i].setAttribute("class", "myClass")
```

Comment: Thanks but I am just trying to target a single set of <p> tags with the class of wpm_err.

Comment: then use getAttribute("class") and compare first and maybe update your question with any additional modifiers/clarifications